# Read a timestamp value from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to display some data in a SSRS Report and I have an issue.

For intormation, I have to use existing Stored Procedures and the SQL user I have to use can only execute Stored Procedures.

What I wanted to do is to create Temp Table, insert data on it and then handle it..

But the thing is that one of the SP I have to use returns a field of type TimeStamp (RoVersion) and I'm not able to read data returned from that stored procedure.

Here is an exemple:

```
Declare @Temp Table (id int, name varchar(50), RowVersion TimeStamp)

INSERT INTO @Temp 
EXEC usp_MySP
```

The error I have is:

> "Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column."

Do you have any idea to solve this? Or even an other way to do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare your column as `varbinary(8)` instead:

```
Declare @Temp Table (id int, name varchar(50), RowVersion varbinary(8))

INSERT INTO @Temp 
EXEC usp_MySP
```

See [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182776.aspx):

> A nonnullable **rowversion** column is semantically equivalent to a **binary(8)** column. A nullable **rowversion** column is semantically equivalent to a **varbinary(8)** column.